# Java Jpanel color not appearing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, thread-sleep

Hello i was studying about 2d graphics and wanted to make something like this 
http://i60.tinypic.com/71tm37.png

my code for the frame and declaration of the Jpanel is this :

```
public class Animation extends JPanel {
private ArrayList<BouncingCircle> circles;
Animation() {
this.setSize(320, 240);
this.setOpaque(true);
this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 102));      
circles = new ArrayList<BouncingCircle>();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Image dbImg = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    Graphics dbg = dbImg.getGraphics();
    draw(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImg, 0, 0, this);
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
        BouncingCircle bc = circles.get(i);
        bc.draw(g);
    }
    repaint();
}

private void addCircle() {
    BouncingCircle bc = new BouncingCircle();
    circles.add(bc);
    Thread t = new Thread(bc);
    t.start();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame frame  = new JFrame("Game");
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setSize(320,240);
  frame.setResizable(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  Animation a = new Animation();
  frame.getContentPane().add(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a.addCircle();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error: Thread Interrupted.");
        }
    }
   }
```

the BouncingCircle class here:

```
public class BouncingCircle implements Runnable {
private int x;
private int y;
private int xVelocity;
private int yVelocity;

BouncingCircle() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    xVelocity = 2;
    yVelocity = 2;
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        move();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error: Thread Interrupted.");
        }
    }
}

private void move() {
x += xVelocity;
y += yVelocity;
if (x < 0)
    xVelocity = 2;
if (x > 320)
    xVelocity = -2;
if (y < 0)
    yVelocity = 2;
if (y > 240)
    yVelocity = -2;
}

void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
  }
 }
```

but it doesnt show the backgroundcolor i tried with frame.add(a) but still not working

Comment: It works for me. But I removed the `a.addCircle();` line as I don't have the complete `Animation` class. Likely there is something in that method that fits the panel and hides the background

Comment: Thread.sleep isn't going to help. You've overridden one of the paint methods in your Aniamtion panel haven't you

Comment: removed  a.addCircle() and anyway it didn't work

Comment: yes i overrided the paint method  and draw method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable cause is you've overridden one of the paint methods and not called its equivalent super method.

Remember paint does a lot of important things, like panting the background.
The probable cause is you've overridden one of the paint methods and not called its equivalent super method.

Remember paint does a lot of important things, like panting the background.

Take a look at [Performing Customing Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

**Updated**

This is your problem right here...

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Image dbImg = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    Graphics dbg = dbImg.getGraphics();
    draw(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImg, 0, 0, this);
}
```

The basic problem is, you've broken the paint chain, meaning that all the important work that paint does, like paint the background, isn't getting done.

Also, Swing components are already double buffered, so you don't need to use `createImage` and you shouldn't be overriding `paint`, but instead `paintComponent`

So, get rid of `paint` and use...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    draw(g);
}
```

Instead...
Take a look at [Performing Customing Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Verified, works just fine!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Animation extends JPanel {
    // private ArrayList<BouncingCircle> circles;

    Animation() {
        this.setSize(320, 240);
        this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 102));
        // circles = new ArrayList<BouncingCircle>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(320, 240);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Animation a = new Animation();
        frame.getContentPane().add(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // a.addCircle();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.err.println("Error: Thread Interrupted.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah it worked i will show the other class looks like the problem is on BouncingCircle , i deleted a.addCircle() but it didnt show the background color

Answer (score 0):

This'll work:

```
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Image dbImg = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());     
        Graphics dbg = dbImg.getGraphics();
        draw(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImg, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 102));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
            BouncingCircle bc = circles.get(i);
            bc.draw(g);
        }
        repaint();
    }
```

If you painting a full-size image over your panel, you should **fill image's background** then.

Comment: yeah worked thank you i will continue studying about paint method  thanks for your  help